# "A proposito" auf Deutsch

Tags: translation, idiom, colloquial

"A proposito" ist eine Italienische Redewendung, die man (meistens) am Anfang des Satzes benutzt. Wie wäre es auf Deutsch? Das soll nicht literarisch, sondern eher umgangsprächlich, unformell sein.

Comment: Mhh...[apropos](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/apropos)?

Comment: Und für alle, die des italienischen nicht mächtig sind: Warum sagt man das am Anfang des Satzes? – Und überhaupt, warum ist ein [Dictionary](http://dict.leo.org/itde/index_de.html#/search=A%20proposito&searchLoc=0&resultOrder=basic&multiwordShowSingle=on) hier nicht ausreichend?

Comment: @Jan: Da stellt jemand, der laut Profil 20 Jahre lang in Italien unterrichtet hat, eine Frage in Deutscher Sprache, bei der es um eine italienische Phrase geht, und du schreibst einen englischen Kommentar. Warum Englisch? Warum nicht Deutsch, oder meinetwegen Italienisch? Das hier ist ein DEUTSCH-Forum, kein Englisch-Forum! Wenn der Fragensteller seine Frage schon auf Deutsch formuliert, wird er ziemlich sicher einen deutschen Kommentar verstehen können. Man kann nicht immer davon ausgehen, dass alle, die dieses Deutsch-Forum besuchen, auch Englisch sprechen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***A proposito*** ist logischerweise das italienische äquivalent zu dem deutschen Wort ***apropos***.

Umganssprachliche Übersetzungen wären:

- übrigens
- nebenbei
- im Zusammenhang
- ...